# How can I retrieve a Gitlab Project tag list through the API?

Tags: rest, gitlab

I'm writing a REST client to look at project information available from several gitlab servers at the same time in one consolidated place. I understand REST and am able to pull the project details I need except one: the tags.

I'm not talking about git repository tags, those I'm able to get to just fine. I'm referring to the tags that are set under Project Settings. These are tags that, from what I can tell, are meant to be a form of describing the project, not referencing a particular commit hash.

Comment: Is there a GraphiQL API to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I submitted a merge request back to the Gitlab folks, if accept, any REST call that involves a Project class will include a "tag_list" field with all the project labels.

The merge request is available here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/329

EDIT: This was merged in Gitlab version 7.10.0 so now you can just run a GET on the Project and the tag_list will be included with the JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
http://www.example.com.br/api/v3/projects/#{str}/repository/tags?private_token=yourtoken"
```

Note that in `#{str}` variable, if you using a group/repository structure, you must replace the dash to `%2F`, for example, you must set:

```
http://www.example.com.br/api/v3/projects/group%2Frepository/repository/tags?private_token=yourtoken"
```

The response to your request will be the **body**. So you can console log response.body to retrieve the tags.

Comment: This no longer works, you need v4 instead: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/group%2Frepository/repository/tags`

Answer (score 0):

Not possible: ACCEPTING MERGE REQUEST at: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6325819-project-labels-via-api , so feel free to implement it if you need it.

Should be simple: just return the `project.tag_list` (see: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) as a JSON list from https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/41518a467dcef61deca24ad2f6205c6fd5706e1b/lib/api/projects.rb#L60

Always check the request tracker first for features ;) True, in this case you may have done it an not found because of `label` vs `tag` keyword confusion, I think it was renamed at some point, so always search for both.

Answer (score 0):

And is it possible to get by **API** just a list of tags with repositories whose comets the tags belong to? Now on version 14.5.2 (and later), GitLab gives information on repositories with an empty array of tags (tag_list[0]). The only way to get a tag is to request tags in the API with an indication of a specific repository, but I have hundreds of them (repositories), and it doesn't seem quite right to send hundreds of http requests every time...